# is there such a thing as a cross-browser css language abstraction?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was setting up a div min height today and had to do this (thanks to [http://css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/)):

```
min-height: 500px; 
height:auto !important; 
height: 500px;
```

OK not a big deal, but it's a bit obnoxious -- to get min-height to work cross browser I had to spend 5 minutes googling it and making sure it worked.

I wonder if there's a cross-browser css language that will abstract away these sort of things. For instance, I'd like to express min-height once and have it work for all browsers in the same way that jquery abstracts away these sort of things. Maybe in a markup like Styl. Does such an animal exist?

Comment: Um... CSS is (intended to be) a 'cross browser', universal standard! :)  It's up to whomever implements the standard to get it right.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support `min-height`, there's nothing you can do, really, except for Javascript shims maybe. `height` and `min-height` behave differently, so your solution is not really "cross-browser".

Comment: The short answer would be no, if you want to support older browsers, you just gotta deal with it. If however you need to use `min-height` or whatever in lots of places and want to just use a single line throughout, you could use something like Sass mix-ins.

Comment: @PlanB LOL that was good for a laugh. My point is that Jquery manages to abstract these cross browser idiosyncracies away, I wonder if there's a similar thing for CSS.

Comment: @jcollum -- Try normalize.css or using the HTML5Boilerplate reset block -- they apply a set of 'base styles' to normalize default behaviors of elements.  Outside of that -- there's not much you can do!  http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: @PlanB interesting, will check it out, thanks

Comment: I agree with @ultranaut if you're trying to support old browsers without extra typing Sass / SCSS would be the way to go.